# Vote To Close? Vote to Close

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, grammar

It is commonly held that [titles do not capitalize their prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5007/100525). When I open the close dialog I see this:

> [image: Vote To Close button]

This doesn't seem right. It should read "Vote **to** Close" network-wide.

Comment: I thought it is some test question posted with some off-topic text and asking users to vote to close XD

Comment: @NogShine There's no valid reason to close this question, just upvote. ;)

Comment: Here you are technically correct, though the issue is insignificant and the proposal leaves a bit of room for bickering. The perfect meta post! +1.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to call this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) since the close menu was updated and our Stacks guidance explicitly calls for sentence case rather than title case, so the text now reads "Vote to close" instead.

> [image: Image of "Vote to close" button in the close vote menu]

(thanks to Panda for the screenshot)